# Unable to get records from atlas after migrate local mongo db into atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongo-shell, dbmigrate

i migrate local db into atlas using following process

1. export db collection one by one using `mongoexport --db bla
   --collection usersettings --jsonArray --out ~/Desktop/users.json` command
2. import these collection on atlas using `mongoimport --host
   cluster0-shard-00-00-c7jiq.mongodb.net:27017 --db Eltar --type json
   --file ~/Desktop/userotp.json --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username name --password pass` command

Now, when i connect to local mongo shell and run the query `db.users.find()` it shows all the record but when i run the same query `db.users.find()` after connecting atlas shell it shows only one record.

Records are showing on atlas but unable to get them using query

dont know what i am doing wrong here, any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Done by migrating `mongo db` to `mlab` instead of `mongo db atlas`, still don't know the issue. But everything works fine on `mlab`